# Why won't bottom div move up when middle div is hidden?

Tags: jquery, layout, html, hide

I have three divs that are float left stacked on top of each other. When I hide the middle div using `$('#divMiddle').hide('slow')`, the bottom div does not immediately float up to fill the space that was vacated. Sometimes it moves up after a few seconds and other times it takes almost a minute. Am I missing a jQuery or JavaScript command to force this to happen immediately?

Comment: Do you have any code you can show?  Maybe post it on http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can play around with the code a bit

Comment: Did you try to hide immidiatly (without the 'slow') ?

Comment: We need to see both the HTML and relevant javascript code.  `hide()` will set to `display: none` when the animation is done.  If other objects don't move up into its place, then that's because of the HTML/CSS.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the case with this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dmt48/

Answer (score 0):

If your using Firebug or chrome, have you tried inspecting the empty space to sanity check that there is no other elements and it is using display:none vs. visibility?